# How to save and work with previous iteration in loop?

Tags: python, numpy, loops, for-loop

You could somehow hold it in a loop after the first iteration and store it in a variable and then continue on. So that in one variable there is a standard loop and in the other a previous loop?

example:

```
import numpy as np

for j in np.arange(0,5):
    print(j)


0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

i need example

```
0
1 0
2 1
3 2 
4 3
5 4 
6 5
```

Answer (score 0):

just save the variable you want to print next, and print it before change it with the next one

```
num = 0
for j in np.arange(0,5):
    print(num)  
    num = j
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

for j in np.arange(0,7):
    if j == 0:
        print(j)
        continue
    print(j, j-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` and `itertools.tee`:

```
itr1, itr2 = tee(np.arange(0, 5))
i, j = next(itr1), None

print(i, j)
for i, j in zip(itr1, itr2):
    print(i, j)
```

outputs

```
0 None
1 0
2 1
3 2
4 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is poorly worded, but here's a good basic iteration.  It keeps track of the current variable, as well as saving it.

```
In [161]: alist = [1,3,6,9,12]
     ...: blist = []
     ...: latest = None
     ...: for item in alist:
     ...:     blist.append(item)
     ...:     print(latest, blist[-1])
     ...:     latest = item
     ...: print(blist)
None 1
1 3
3 6
6 9
9 12
[1, 3, 6, 9, 12]
```

In the iteration, the current value is `item`, the previous is `latest`.  `blist[-1]` is the last added item.